# Parquet compression type via Impala

Tags: impala, parquet

We have quite a few impala tables defined, and assume we are using Snappy compression. (parquet files)

However nobody really knows what compression type we are actually using on existing tables.

The impala docs don't seem to specify how to get the compression type from an existing table.

Is there a way to find the used compression type via impala?

Comment: Hypothetically, you could use `DESCRIBE FORMATTED $table_name`, but [the "Compressed:" field in that result is unreliable:  "It typically always shows No, because the compression settings only apply during the session that loads data and are not stored persistently with the table metadata."](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_describe.html)

Comment: Agreed, on parquet tables it would just show you 'NO'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of right now there is no command in Impala that would tell you the type of compression being used in a table stored as parquet, but there is a work around. What you can do is look at one of the parquet files within the table and then use the parquet-tools meta command in order to see the compression being used.

```
-- step1) run hdfs dfs -ls to determine the location and name for a parquet file
hdfs dfs -ls /yourTableLocationPath
-- step2) parquet-tools really only works locally right now so you will need to copy the file to a local directory
hdfs dfs -get /yourTableLocationPath/yourFileName /yourLocalPath
-- step3) run parquet-tools meta command
parquet-tools meta /yourLocalPath/yourFileName
```

The output of the parquet-tools meta command will show you the type of compression being used under the row group output.